# How can I install i386 packages on Ubuntu aarch64?

Tags: server, repository, 32-bit, vps, arm64

I want to install `steamcmd` on my Ubuntu aarch64 VPS, to do that I added a i386 architecture with the command `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then doing a update and it showing me : [theses following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMXqC.png).

I couldn't find a way to install steamcmd on a aarch64 architecture.

Version: Ubuntu 22.04.1
Kernel: 5.15.0-1018-oracle aarch64 GNU/Linux
Architecture:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
   i386
~$ sudo dpkg --print-architecture
   arm64
```

Repositories:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://eu-marseille-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

If anyone can help me it will be very nice !

Comment: @muru thanks but I want to install steamcmd for a server not for playing game on my VPS, but thanks a lot to trying to help me !

Comment: Either way, I think the point in the top answer stands - you're not going to be able to use it without an emulator like QEMU or Box86 or something. Just installing the steamcmd package isn't going to help.

Comment: @muru So my only solution is to get another VPS with a compatible kernel with steamcmd ?

Comment: If you can, that will be the least painful way. You can try using the emulators if that's not an option